# html select option style error while adding data-live-search="true"

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using adminBSB template for a portal, but all select boxes went [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzICs.png)

It's occurring only on Windows OS, but in Linux os it's working fine.

It's happening because of data-live-search = "true".

Please give me a solution

```
<select class = "form-control show-tick" onchange = "showQuantityPerUnit(); typeForward(this.value);" data-live-search = "true" name = "type" id = "type" required>
<option value="">SELECT TYPE</option>
  <?php $MedicineType = $DataControl -> Read("type", "");
    foreach ($MedicineType as $TypeKey) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $TypeKey['type']; ?>"><?php echo $TypeKey['type']; ?></option>
  <? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I've added a code snippet, please check @MrLister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encounter this issue, and i think it is an issue about the web browser compatibility, and not the operating system. it is working fine in mozilla firefox and older versions of google chrome. I know this question is a month's old. but for those who still don't know the fix for this issue. do this.

you may fix it by updating your style.css.

```
.bootstrap-select .bs-searchbox .form-control,
.bootstrap-select .bs-actionsbox .form-control,
.bootstrap-select .bs-donebutton .form-control {margin-left : 30px}
```

to

```
.bootstrap-select .bs-searchbox .form-control,
.bootstrap-select .bs-actionsbox .form-control,
.bootstrap-select .bs-donebutton .form-control {padding-left : 30px}
```

hope it helps.